# Add UIButton to overlay on top of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift

As the question states, I want to add a `UIButton` on top of a table View (at the bottom) inside my view controller. As I understand it, you can't add any views on top of a table view in general, or at least that's what I think based on what I've tried:

```
let shareButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
shareButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)
shareButton.backgroundColor = imageColors[currentTeam.homeName]
shareButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
shareButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)
shareButton.setTitle("Send!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
shareButton.addTarget(self, action: "send:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

//Tried this
self.view.insertSubview(shareButton, aboveSubview: self.tableView)

//And this
self.view.addSubview(shareButton)

//Also tried making a toolbar. But that didn't work either
var toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.height - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)
self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

The effect I want to achieve is something similar to what snapchat has:
[image: what i want]

Comment: what's not working? Can you view debug it?

Comment: The button won't appear at all. Maybe it's hidden behind the tableView?...no idea

Comment: view debug to see whether the button is there. `addSubview:` should work.

Answer (score 0):

The possible problem is that you are using an instance of `UITableViewController`. In this case your `self.view` points to an instance of `UITableView`, and your button won't appear.

To fix that, you should use an instance of `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`, and add `UITableView` to view controller manually via storyboard. Then you're able to add button and other UI elements to `self.view`, because it will point to an instance of `UIView`.

Actually, I preffer to use `UIViewController` instead of `UITableViewController`, until I am not sure that `UITableViewController` is a way to go.

So, make sure you aren't using the `UITableViewController`.

[image]

Comment: No - it's a view controller with a tableView embedded inside.

Comment: @RaymondRangel so, try to set `shareButton.backgroundColor` explicitly, for example with red color and check if it actually appears. Then try to move button to front via `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(shareButton)`. Magic doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with your code(with  self.view.addSubview(shareButton)) its working

[image: Screen shot]

In case if you want to see code, I am pasting here ..

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let shareButton = UIButton()
    shareButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 50, self.view.frame.size.width, 50)
    shareButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    shareButton.tintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    shareButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 16)
    shareButton.setTitle("Send!", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    shareButton.addTarget(self, action: "send:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    self.view.addSubview(shareButton)


     data = ["Ajay","Ajay","AJay","Ajay","Ajay","AJay","Ajay","Ajay","AJay","Ajay","Ajay","AJay","Ajay","Ajay","AJay","Ajay","Ajay","AJay","Ajay","Ajay","AJay","Ajay","Ajay","AJay"]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return data!.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell?

    if cell == nil {

        cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Value1, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }

    cell!.selectionStyle             = .None
    cell!.textLabel?.text           = data![indexPath.row]

    return cell!
}
```

Comment: You need to do `self.parent.view.addSubview(shareButton)`

Answer (score 0):

was your view controller a UItableviewcontroller ? , if that ,you can not add a btn like that, because self.view in you code is a uitableview. you should consider use UIViewController + UItableview  instead of a UITableviewcontrller.